# Character, Line and Word Counter in C

Tags: c

I am sorry to ask so many questions but I am clueless what to do when my Program gives me errors which I don't understand how to fix. I use Code Blocks. The book name is The C Programming Language 2nd Edition.

The Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define IN 1
#define OUT 0

int main()
{
    int c, nl, nw, nc, state;
    state = OUT;
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        ++nc;
        if (c == '\n')
            if (c == '' || c == '\n' || c = '\t')
            state = OUT;
        else if (state == OUT) {
            state = IN;
            ++nw;
        }
    }
    printf("%d %d %d \n", nl, nw, nc);
}
```

So when I build it it gives me error on line 14 saying:

```
||=== Build: Debug in Line Counter v2 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\Users\Uddhava\Desktop\Uddhava\Learning\Programming\C C+\Line Counter v2\
main.c|14|error: empty character constant|

C:\Users\Uddhava\Desktop\Uddhava\Learning\Programming\C C+\Line Counter v2\
main.c|14|error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment|

||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 2 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: You don't seem to have transcribed the code accurately.  There should be `if (c == '\n') nl++;` and then the faulty condition that was on line 14.  As it is written, you have the second `if` statement only being executed when `c == '\n'`, which is not what is intended.

Comment: You also need to set each of `nl`, `nw` and `nc` to zero before incrementing any of them; otherwise, you get indeterminate starting values for your counts.

Comment: these lines: if (c == '\n')
            if (c == '' || c == '\n' || c = '\t')  'c' could not possibly equal ' ' nor '\n' nor '\t' because the first line already confirmed that 'c' is '\n'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this worked, I used ideas from Amadeus, user3629249 and Min Fu. Thanks everyone for your help.

Working Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define IN 1
#define OUT 0

int main()
{
int c, nl, nw, nc, state;
state = OUT;
nc = 0;
nl = 0;
nw = 0;
while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
{
++nc;
if (('\n' == c) || (' ' == c) || ('\n' == c) || ('\t' == c) )
{
    state = OUT;
    ++nl;
}
else if (state == OUT)
{
    state = IN;
    ++nw;
}
}
printf("%d %d %d \n", nl, nw, nc);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
if (c == '' || c == '\n' || c = '\t')
```

should be

```
 if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')


if (c == '\n')
    if (c == '' || c == '\n' || c = '\t')
```

In your code, the first if statement makes the second meaningless.

Comment: C:\Users\Uddhava\Desktop\Uddhava\Learning\Programming\C C+\Line Counter v2\main.c|14|error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment|   That error stays And my book says it has to be blank

Comment: If you're still getting an error, it means that you didn't make both changes that he gave you.   You noticed that two things changed from the original you provided, correct?

Comment: I am sorry didnt see the second change but int nl gives me 4200798

Comment: I tried different sentences but int nl still gives me 4200798

Answer (score 4):

```
if (c == '' || c == '\n' || c = '\t')
```

The first thing wrong with this line is that it should be:

```
if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
```

Comment: For the record, when I started typing this answer there were no others yet posted for this question!

Comment: Please look at the comment in the first answer and when I run it the program just ends

Comment: You shouldn't get down-voted for producing a similar answer to others within a minute or two of the other answers.  If you waited 10 minutes to hit submit, the harsher assessors might down-vote.

Comment: @UddhavaSwaminathan: the answers are presented in quasi-random orders, partly depending on chosen sort order, partly depending on score of the answer at the time when the user refreshed.  Identifying an answer by place is tricky, therefore.  You can use the 'share' link underneath an answer to generate an x-ref URL.  Or you could add a note to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You are testing the value of `c` against an empty character constant `''`, which is not allowed. I think you want to test it against a space `' '`.

Comment: That's one part of the problem.  There are two parts to the problem.

Comment: Please look at the comment in the first answer and when I run it the program just ends

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test the value of your variable `c` with an empty space, you should compare it with `' '` instead of `''`. Furthermore, comparison operator is `==`, not `=` (assignment), which you used to compare the tab character `'\t'` in the last condition of your if statement, thus your if statement should be:

```
if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
```

Answer (score 1):

this code block:

```
while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
{
    ++nc;
    if (c == '\n')
        if (c == '' || c == '\n' || c = '\t')
        state = OUT;
    else if (state == OUT) {
        state = IN;
        ++nw;
    }
}

does not indicate (via the indentation) exactly which 'if' clause 
is related to the 'else clause.  
this is a VERY good reason to include ALL the '{' and '}' braces

this is what is actually written in the code:

while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
{
    ++nc;
    if (c == '\n')
    {
        if (c == '' || c == '\n' || c = '\t') // two errors on this line
        {
            state = OUT;
        }
        else if (state == OUT) 
        {
            state = IN;
            ++nw;
        }
    }
}

the question becomes:  is this what you really wanted?
we already know that the code is not correct
because the second 'if' will ALWAYS fail due to 'c' being
already confirmed as containing a '\n'
and the comparison of 'c' to ''
and the assignment of '\t' to 'c'

therefore, I suspect it should be:

while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
{
    ++nc;
    if (('\n' == c) || (' ' == c) || ('\n' == c) || ('\t' == c) ) 
    {
        state = OUT;
    }
    else if (state == OUT) 
    {
        state = IN;
        ++nw;
    }
}

which would have also caught the assignment of '\t' to c at compile time
rather than you having to spend many an hour debugging the code.
I.E. put the literal on the left side of the comparison operator '=='
```